# CefSharp version 53 how to get document ready event

Tags: cefsharp

I'm trying to read page source once the document is fully loaded. But I cannot find an event for it. I searched topics over stackoverflow and github. The event used to do the job "NavStateChanged" is no longer available in version 53.

If I use "LoadingStateChanged" event, I can receive the "IsLoading" state change from false to true, meaning user is leaving the page. What I need is "IsLoading" changed from true to false (finished entering the page). I tried several other event, none of them works for this purpose. So I'm just using a timer looping on the background to find this change. Is there a better solution on this?

Comment: NavStateChanged was simply renamed to LoadingStateChanged a few years ago as that matches the CEF API. Read the general usage guide on the wiki, you can inject JavaScript to hook the domcontentloaded event.

Comment: Also IsLoading will transition from true to false, not the other way around

Comment: Not sure but I use the FrameLoadEnd event on the browser control to load some extra css in the page. Seems to work fine.